# How to print a string list as a single string without intermediate characters

Tags: python, string, list

```
def main():
 key = []

 mess=input('Write Text: ')

 for ch in mess:
     x = ord(ch)
     x = x-3
     x = chr(x)
     key.append(x)

 print("Your code message is: ",key)

 outFile = open("Encryptedmessage.txt","w")
 print(key, file=outFile)

main()
```

so far i have written this a it works fine but my problem is the output is

```
Write Text: the
Your code message is:  ['q', 'e', 'b']
```

and i was wondering how you would get rid of the punction so the output would be

```
Write Text: the
Your code message is:  qeb
```

Comment: Shouldn't the duplicate flag point to a question that is not _itself_ a duplicate? :-)

Answer (score 2):

`key` is a list.  You can use `join(list)` to join the elements of the list together:

```
print("Your code message is: ", "".join(key))
```

> `str.join(iterable)`
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
>   iterable iterable. The separator between elements is the string
>   providing this method.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?#str.join

You don't want any separator characters in between the elements of the list, so use an empty string `""` as the separator.

Comment: You're mixing up the string method `join()` with `join` from the (mostly) obsolete `string` module. `"".join` has no `sep` argument, nor does it need one.

Comment: You're right. My apologies. Edited to reference the correct `join()`

Comment: okay but then how to you get it to look like qeb with the file as well

Comment: Assign the output of the join to a variable.  For example: `joinedkey="".join(key)`. Use that variable (i.e. `joinedkey`) in place of `key` in your print statements. For example: `print(joinedkey, file=outFile)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe replace

```
key=[]
```

with

```
key=""
```

and replace

```
key.append(x)
```

with

```
key=key+x
```

?